# How to forward the file stream fetched from axios and return it to the front-end?

Tags: nestjs

How to forward the file stream fetched from axios and return it to the front-end?

In nest, I'm using axios to get a content-type: "application/octet-stream" file stream from somewhere, I can get this file in, but how do I return this file to the front end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
// service
this.httpService.get(`...`, {
      params: {
        ...
      },
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});

// controller
async export(@Req() req: any, @Res() res) {
    res.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=xxx.xlsx');
    res.header('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');

    const _buffer = await this.Service.export(id);
    return await res.send(_buffer.data);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).